# Having trouble getting jQuery UI resizable working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious (it's late in the day).

I've set up a test page with a really basic implementation of jQuery UI resizable. Why isn't it working and allowing the elements to be resizable?

http://jsfiddle.net/UA3QS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that there's just some problems with the CSS, and the handle which you'd use to resize isn't even visible (it has no width and height). Here's a simple edit of your example that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/UA3QS/2/

Comment: very interesting, that your edit works.  i tried removing all the css (which should work) and it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with jQuery Ui 1.8.4

the demo pages for jQuery ui are running 1.8.3   and i just did a quick local test and it worked fine and i have 1.8.3 locally.

or jsFiddle is broken...

here's an example that is also broken that has no CSS to break it.
http://jsfiddle.net/PAsgQ/2/

Comment: I initially tried it with UI 1.8.5 locally and it wasn't working.

Comment: give 1.8.3 a try maybe?  the face taht your resizer handle wasn't visible would explain why one the one wasn't resizeable, but not why something without a handle wasn't

Comment: Where can I download it from? I've looked in the obvious places (official site/GitHub/Google search) and it's proving to be quite elusive.